# How to use jQuery BlockUI in the master page to load Please wait Message..

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I need to implement jquery blockUI for my application.. I have this code..

```
 $.blockUI({ css: { 
            border: 'none', 
            padding: '15px', 
            backgroundColor: '#000', 
            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
            opacity: .5, 
            color: '#fff' 
        } }); 

        setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
    });
```

I am keeping this code in each click function in my views.. then it working fine. but I need to make this code centralized that is keeping this code in master file if something is taking more than 2000 milliseconds can I show do jQuery BlockUI? for my entire application. if so please can any one help me out how to keep this code in master page what kind of code I need to implement in master page to access this jQuery blockUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this way:

In the masterpage I have added the script reference and a reference to a custom script where I have the following code

```
//Set Defaults values for blockUI
$.blockUI.defaults.theme = true;
$.blockUI.defaults.title = 'Please wait...';
$.blockUI.defaults.message = '<img src="_assets/images/blockUI_Loader.gif" />';
$.blockUI.defaults.css = {};
$.blockUI.defaults.themedCSS = {};
$.blockUI.defaults.themedCSS.width = 100;
$.blockUI.defaults.themedCSS.height = 64;
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS = {};
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
$.blockUI.defaults.overlayCSS.opacity = 0.6;
```

Then when I have to use it in ajax calls I simply use

```
$("#element").block();
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    dataType: "html",
    url: "some/url",
    data: {},
    success: function (response, status, xml) {
        $("#element").unblock();
    },
    error: function (response) {
        $("#element").unblock();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Lorenzo.. what is element tag?

Comment: I think Lorenzo can we do something like this?$(document).ajaxSend(aSend).ajaxStop(aStop);   var aSend = function() {
       
         $.blockUI();
      
    }
    var aStop = function() {
        $.unblockUI();
    }

Comment: element is the markup element you want to block (e.g. a form, a div, etc). This is useful when you want to block only some part of your page and not all the page. If you want to block all the page you can use blockUi function or just use the id of your body element

Answer (score 1):

To make it accessible everywhere without writing it over and over again, you can place the code in a function()

for example, place this in your global javascript file:

```
function blockUI(){
// $.blockUI({ css: {...
}
```

Then anywhere you need it, call blockUI();

Comment: Yes Adrian its working for me.. one question is.. is there any way that we can do instead of calling  blockUI() in every where in my views..can we do something? on any button click if its taking more time can we show this message automatically? without calling blockUI() funcation? correct me if I am wrong? thanks