# How to move jquery blockUI message bit Up

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

i am working with jquery blockUI. always processing text coming at center. i tried to change it position bit but i failed. i tried by css like

```
            $('div#SearchResult').block({ message: '<table cellspacing="5" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top: 6px;"><tr><td style="width:30px" align="right" valign="middle"><img  src="../images/ajx-loader.gif" border="0"/></td><td style="width:100px" align="left" valign="middle"><h3>Processing...</h3></td></tr></table>',
            css: {
                border: '10px solid #CCCCCC', height: '50px', top: '200px'
            }
        });
```

here i mention the message div top will 200px but it is not going to take effect even i tried like normal css as example

```
.blockUI 
{
    top: 200px;
}
```

but nothing works. so please anyone tell me how could i move the message box div to bit upper by css. thanks

At last i could figure out how to fix it

---

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#block').click(function () {
            $('#mydv').block({
                message: 'Processing...', centerY: false,
                css:
                { 
                    //background-color: 'white',
                    border: '3px solid #a00',
                    top: '110px',
                    position:'fixed',
                    width:'100px'
                    //, height: '40px'
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Have you used an inspector (Firebug, Chrome Web Tools, etc) to see what CSS property is setting the position of the message? That'd be where I'd start, modify the CSS such that the message moves, then make that change in your code.

Comment: Your upper code works nicely for me... Are the other css properties (height, border) applied correctly?

Comment: jquery blockUi message div has no id...has many css class has been assign. so anyone can tell how to access jquery blockUi message div programmatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854299/jquery-blockui-positoning-question?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751976/jquery-plugin-blockui-doesnt-gray-out-screen-in-firefox?rq=1

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581079/blockui-positioning-on-the-page-not-the-screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367653/how-to-use-jquery-blockui-in-the-master-page-to-load-please-wait-message

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/stylesheet.html

Comment: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#faq